# Add JavaFX jmods to java --list-modules

Tags: java, javafx, module-path

## Preface:

I need to open .jar files which requires Java and JavaFX. I have installed both Java ([from Oracle website](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html)) and JavaFX ([SDK from openjfx website](http://gluonhq.com/download/javafx-12-0-2-sdk-linux/)). I have added environment variables by updating `/etc/environment` file, and adding `JAVAFX_HOME="path/to/JavaFX"`.

`/etc/environment` file looks like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.2/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.2"
JAVAFX_HOME="/home/joshi/Documents/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib"
```

For now, I can get a .jar file running by executing:

`java --module-path $JAVAFX_HOME --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH -jar myfile.jar`

There are multiple .jar files, which makes executing above command pretty troublesome. Name of .jar files are pretty non-catchy and complex too.

## Question:

I want to know if I can add JavaFX jmods to Java permanently. For example, when we execute in terminal `java --list-modules`, it should include JavaFX mods in it too.

## I have tried:

1. Copying JavaFX jmod files in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.2/jmods`. But even after rebooting, `java --list-modules` doesn't include JavaFX mods. I have also ran

```
    sudo update-alternatives --config java 
    sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

2. I don't think creating .sh script files would be a great idea as there would need to be as many script files as there are .jar files.

Any help is highly appreciated. I am on Kubuntu.

Comment: Have a look at this https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular (section: Custom JDK+JavaFX image). The idea is to create your custom JDK with JavaFX included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use environment variable: `_JAVA_OPTIONS`.
All options specified in this variable will be appended to the JVM startup args.

`export _JAVA_OPTIONS="--module-path=/path/to/JavaFX --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH"`

Comment: Setting `_JAVA_OPTIONS="--module-path /path/to/JavaFX --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH"` threw following error: 
`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:  --module-path /home/sanmay/Documents/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH   Unrecognized option: --module-path   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.  Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: Does it work when you use `=` instead of spaces? For example: `--module-path=/path/to/JavaFX --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH`

Comment: I got also Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine but then I added quotemarks around java fx path: "--module-path=/path/to/JavaFX" and it worked (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Do not download and install the SDK zip file. Instead download and install the jmods zip file.

Comment: would you elaborate on how one does this? jmod files do not appear to be implicitly recognized in the same way. `Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found`